# How to create web modules using VB.net?

Tags: asp.net

I know VB.net and I use modules a lot in VB desktop application. Now I need start to build my web application by using VB ASP.net (VS2010). I want to do some very simple calculation and then display the result. However, I don't see "Add a new module" option in VB ASP.net. Does "module" exist in VB ASP.net? Is it called other name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are called `Class` files.

Right-click on your solution, or folder you wish to add the class and choose `Add new item` then from the window choose `Class`.